# Joining tables based on reference table value

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, normalization

Have these tables
[image]

and given `post_map.tag_id='1'`, I would like to get:
[image]

entity_type table determines what table be look in, i.e. what table entity_id is stored in. My main goal is to get this table as the result of either mysqli::multi_query() or mysqli::query(), i.e. without PHP going back and forth to the database multiple times; this table may have many many rows and getting this table at once would much more efficient.

My attempts thus far:

- I have tried JOIN clause but I don't know how to use the row value of prior SELECT as the table name for the JOIN clause.
- Tried Prepared Statments but can't form anything usable.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by IF() and JOIN. I have solution for you, run below query...

```
SELECT et.type, 
IF(et.type='resource',r.resource_type_id,NULL) AS resource_type_id, 
IF(et.type='resource',r.value,NULL) AS value, 
IF(et.type='user',u.name,NULL) AS name,
IF(et.type='link',l.source,NULL) AS source, 
IF(et.type='link',l.count,NULL) AS count
FROM `post_map` as pm
JOIN `entity_type` as et ON pm.entity_id = et.id
LEFT JOIN `resource` as r ON pm.entity_type_id=r.id
LEFT JOIN `user` as u ON pm.entity_type_id=u.id
LEFT JOIN `link` as l ON pm.entity_type_id=l.id
WHERE pm.tag_id='1'
```